# Performing calculations on DataFrames of different lengths

Tags: python, pandas

I have two different DataFrames that look something like this:

| Lat | Lon |
| --- | --- |
| 28.13 | -87.62 |
| 28.12 | -87.65 |
| ...... | ...... |

| Calculated_Dist_m |
| --- |
| 34.5 |
| 101.7 |
| .............. |

The first DataFrame (name=`df`) (consisting of the `Lat` and `Lon` columns) has just over 1000 rows (values) in it. The second DataFrame (name=`new_calc_dist`) (consisting of the `Calculated_Dist_m` column) has over 30000 rows (values) in it. I want to determine the new longitude and latitude coordinates using the `Lat`, `Lon`, and `Calculated_Dist_m` columns. Here is the code I've tried:

```
r_earth = 6371000
new_lat = df['Lat'] + (new_calc_dist['Calculated_Dist_m'] / r_earth) * (180/np.pi)
new_lon = df['Lon'] + (new_calc_dist['Calculated_Dist_m'] / r_earth) * (180/np.pi) / np.cos(df['Lat'] * np.pi/180)
```

When I run the code, however, it only gives me new calculations for certain index values, and gives me NaNs for the rest. I'm not entirely sure how I should go about writing the code so that new longitude and latitude points are calculated for each of over 30000 row values based on the initial 1000 longitude and latitude points. Any suggestions?

*EDIT*

Here would be some sample outputs. Note that these are not exact figures, but give the idea.

| Lat | Lon |
| --- | --- |
| 28.13 | -87.62 |
| 28.12 | -87.65 |
| 28.12 | -87.63 |
| ..... | ...... |

| Calculated_Dist_m |
| --- |
| 34.5 |
| 101.7 |
| 28.6 |
| 30.8 |
| 76.5 |
| ................. |

And so the sample out put would be:

| Lat | Lon |
| --- | --- |
| 28.125 | -87.625 |
| 28.15 | -87.61 |
| 28.127 | -87.623 |
| 28.128 | -87.623 |
| 28.14 | -87.615 |
| 28.115 | -87.655 |
| 28.14 | -87.64 |
| 28.117 | -87.653 |
| 28.118 | -87.653 |
| 28.15 | -87.645 |
| 28.115 | -87.635 |
| 28.14 | -87.62 |
| 28.115 | -87.613 |
| 28.117 | -87.633 |
| 28.118 | -87.633 |
| ...... | ....... |

Again, these are just random outputs (I tried getting the exact calculations, but could not get it to work). But overall, this gives an idea of what would be wanted: taking the coordinates from the first dataframe and calculating new coordinates based on each of the calculated distances from the second dataframe.

Comment: how do you chose which row of df1 is used with a given row of df2?

Comment: Oh, didn't realize that. I'm not too concerned about giving using specific rows in df1 for a given row in df2. The distances could be from any of the coordinate points. Unless I need to specify?

Comment: Please provide a **specific** minimal example. Let's say 3 rows of df1 and 5 of df2 and **the matching expected output**

Comment: Just added, something like that? Or something different?

Comment: What is the logic used to create the sample output?

Comment: Taking each of the lat and lon points from the first dataframe and calculating new lat and lon points using the distance (m) from the second dataframe. Basically, take each initial lat and lon point and calculate the new lat and lon points using each of the five distances. Then doing the same for the next initial lat and lon, and so on. So because there are three coordinates and five distances, there would be 15 total new coordinates calculated.

Comment: OK, then I think [this should work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74210101/16343464)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly and assuming `df1` and `df2` as input, you can perform a cross `merge` to get all combinations of `df1` and `df2` rows, then apply your computation (here as new columns Lat2/Lon2):

```
df = df1.merge(df2, how='cross')
r_earth = 6371000
df['Lat2'] = df['Lat'] + (df['Calculated_Dist_m'] / r_earth) * (180/np.pi)
df['Lon2'] = df['Lon'] + (df['Calculated_Dist_m'] / r_earth) * (180/np.pi) / np.cos(df['Lat'] * np.pi/180)
```

output:

```
      Lat    Lon  Calculated_Dist_m       Lat2       Lon2
0   28.13 -87.62               34.5  28.130310 -87.619648
1   28.13 -87.62              101.7  28.130915 -87.618963
2   28.13 -87.62               28.6  28.130257 -87.619708
3   28.13 -87.62               30.8  28.130277 -87.619686
4   28.13 -87.62               76.5  28.130688 -87.619220
5   28.12 -87.65               34.5  28.120310 -87.649648
6   28.12 -87.65              101.7  28.120915 -87.648963
7   28.12 -87.65               28.6  28.120257 -87.649708
8   28.12 -87.65               30.8  28.120277 -87.649686
9   28.12 -87.65               76.5  28.120688 -87.649220
10  28.12 -87.63               34.5  28.120310 -87.629648
11  28.12 -87.63              101.7  28.120915 -87.628963
12  28.12 -87.63               28.6  28.120257 -87.629708
13  28.12 -87.63               30.8  28.120277 -87.629686
14  28.12 -87.63               76.5  28.120688 -87.629220
```

Comment: Ah, that seemed to do the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In case you just want the result as two 2D arrays (without repeats of the input, so also `O[m*n]` in memory but 2/5 of the requirement from the result of cross-join):

```py
r_earth = 6371000
z = 180 / np.pi * new_calc_dist['Calculated_Dist_m'].values / r_earth
lat = df['Lat'].values
lon = df['Lon'].values

new_lat = lat[:, None] + z
new_lon = lon[:, None] + z / lat[:, None]
```

Example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([[28.13, -87.62], [28.12, -87.65]], columns=['Lat', 'Lon'])
new_calc_dist = pd.DataFrame([[34.5], [101.7], [60.0]], columns=['Calculated_Dist_m'])

# result of above
>>> new_lat
array([[28.13031027, 28.13091461, 28.13053959],
       [28.12031027, 28.12091461, 28.12053959]])

>>> new_lon
array([[-87.61998897, -87.61996749, -87.61998082],
       [-87.64998897, -87.64996747, -87.64998081]])
```

If you do want those results as `DataFrame`s:

```py
kwargs = dict(index=df.index, columns=new_calc_dist.index)
new_lat = pd.DataFrame(new_lat, **kwargs)
new_lon = pd.DataFrame(new_lon, **kwargs)
```